# HTTP Cache-Control header works only on localhost

Tags: ajax, http, caching, https, browser-cache

I'm trying to configure caching with `Cache-Control` for a REST endpoint in my webapp, it works locally, but when I deploy on our production server the browser just won't cache the responses.

The endpoint is queried via a parametrized ajax request (as shown below).

Some relevant notes :

- I use a *cache buster* parameter (`_`) that is a unix timestamp generated at page load. It doesn't change across ajax requests.
- localhost is on HTTP whereas production is on HTTPS. The certificate is valid and there are no related errors.
- Both Firefox 59.0.2 and Chrome 66.0.3359.139 exhibit this behavior, so I assume this is something in the configuration.

### Localhost

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/events?_=1525720266960&start=2018-04-29&end=2018-06-10
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

=== Request ===
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=<token>
Host: localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/webapp/
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

=== Response ===
Cache-Control: no-transform, max-age=300, private
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 5935
Content-Type: application/json
```

Following requests (for the same parameters) are effectively loaded from cache with the only difference being : `Status Code: 200 OK (from disk cache)`

Which seems fine, since I don't want to revalidate. The resource should only be fetched again, without validation, once it has gone stale after the duration of `max-age` specified by `Cache-Control`.

---

### Production

```
Request URL: https://www.example.org/webapp/rest/events?_=1525720216575&start=2018-04-29&end=2018-06-10
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

=== Request ===
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=<token>
Host: www.example.org
Referer: https://www.example.org/webapp/
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

=== Response ===
Cache-Control: no-transform, max-age=300, private
Connection: close
Content-Length: 5935
Content-Type: application/json
```

In this case, the response is never loaded from cache afterwards.

---

I've stripped some headers that I thought superfluous (`Server`, `X-Powered-By`, `User-Agent`, `Date`).

## Question

**What prevents the reponses to be cached by the browser when talking to the production server ?**

Comment: Both your local and remote request/responses above don't show caching (i.e they are given a 200 instead of 304 or similar). Do you have an example of an output where your caching is working?

Comment: I'm showing the first requests before caching occurs. On localhost the following requests are properly loaded from cache, unfortunately, it doesn't in production. I'll add a cached response from localhost when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 days later I try again and caching works properly. (I swear I'm not insane)

Same request, same headers, same response.

I suspect that it falls into some kind of heuristic that overrides the response `Cache-Control`.

It certainly has to do with the fact that this endpoint did not specify `Cache-Control` before, so the browser overlooks the header since the heuristic favored refetching instead of caching, it can't go wrong about being more cautious.

## [RFC2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

> 13.2.2 Heuristic Expiration
>
> Since origin servers do not always provide explicit expiration times,
>      HTTP caches typically assign heuristic expiration times, employing
>      algorithms that use other header values (such as the Last-Modified
>      time) to estimate a plausible expiration time. The HTTP/1.1
>      specification does not provide specific algorithms, but does impose
>      worst-case constraints on their results. Since heuristic expiration
>      times might compromise semantic transparency, they ought to used
>      cautiously, and we encourage origin servers to provide explicit
>      expiration times as much as possible.

All in all, this is the best explanation I have.

Comment: I too found this unexpected behaviour. Retrying in a private window got it to work as expected and confirm it was the browser playing games.